# MySQL column IN

Tags: mysql

I have a `VARCHAR` column that contains comma separated values and I would like to know if I could match a number within these comma separated values?

Like, I would have a row:

```
id | numbers
1  | 1,2,4,5
2  | 2,3,4,6
```

And I would like to match all the rows with the number 2 in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', numbers) <> 0
```

Comment: So basically I can just do `SELECT FIND_IN_SET(3, test.test) > 0 FROM test`?

Comment: @Manhim Your syntax is a bit off. Take a look at the code sample in my answer.

Comment: `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('3', numbers) <> 0 FROM test`? Seems to be working :)

Comment: @Manhim That's returning the result of the `<>` test, not the actual rows themselves. If that's what you want, great. Just be sure you understand what you're getting back here.

Comment: yes this is what I want for now as well as the comparison in WHERE, but it's always easier to test when it's in the select :)

Answer (score 1):

A version portable across databases would be:

```
where numbers = '2'
    or numbers like '2,%'
    or numbers like '%,2,%'
    or numbers like '%,2'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very efficient, but here's how:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE numbers LIKE '2,%'
    OR numbers LIKE '%,2,%'
    OR numbers LIKE '%,2'
    OR numbers = '2';
```